# CSS Mime Type transferred as Zip in Chrome - 15 second delay

Tags: files

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-gzip: "http://www.energyjustice.net/modules/system/system.base.css?m7sb47".

I turned off the CSS aggregate and compress option, and emptied the Chrome browser cache.  So I'm not sure why I'm still getting this?

If there is nothing in the cache, this error causes Chrome to have a 15 second delay in transferring the system.base.css file.  Firefox works fine.

Drupal 7.14
Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) with mod_gzip/1.3.26.1a 
Chrome 20.0.1132.57

It looks like mod_headers is installed.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the CSS file even has a gzip header.  
This is what it looks like in Chrome Developer Tools: 
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:has_js=1
Host:www.energyjustice.net
If-Modified-Since:Thu, 26 Jul 2012 20:47:57 GMT
If-None-Match:"17e78388-1493-5011acfd"
Referer:http://www.energyjustice.net/fibrowatch
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TOTAL shot in the dark here, but:

1) are you running "Avast!" ?

2) If you load your site and look at network traffic (e.g. "Net" panel in Firebug), are there any 304 responses from the server?

Comment: 1. I'm running Avast!  I turned it off and the problem goes away. Is there any way I can stop my users from having this issue?

2. No 304s.

Comment: my memory on this is quite fuzzy, but it has something to do with Avast! doing their live scanning of web documents and misinterpreting certain headers..  I thought it was related to 304 documents not being empty?

Sorry I can't be of more help, if I get time after work I'll see if I can dig up any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our projects, I found that someone had set zlib.output_compression=On in PHP.INI and this caused chrome and firefox to produce the same problem you are facing.

Turning it back to off solved the issue
(but the surprising thing is that InternetExplorer users did not face this issue in the duration when chrome was complaining)